# Using JIRA REST-API to update a custom field

Tags: api, jira, put, jira-rest-api

I've been trying to set up a new custom webhook in **Zapier**, that automatically updates a custom field in **JIRA**, whenever a specific action occurs. I've followed some tutorials on how to do it, but when I sent the PUT request, it didn't work. I also tested a bunch in postman, but with similar results.

I used this URL:

```
https://bitsandbirds.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/CYBIRD-1252
```

Here is my input:

```
{
   "update" : {
       "customfield_10051" : "test"
   }
}
```

This is what I got back:

```
{
    "errorMessages": [
        "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@498ac517; line: 3, column: 8] (through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean[\"update\"])"
    ]
}
```

Anyone know where I messed up & how to do it right?

[fyi here is the view in Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3rwI.png)

Comment: there are a few things to consider - what is the custom field data type... if its drop down then id should be passed. If its a text then your structure should be fields should be part of JSON. Consider adding update only for summary.... Question is not clear to provide a solution :( https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/

Answer (score -1):

There should be

```
{
  "fields": {
    "customfield_10051" : "test"
  }
}
```